# Nestjs-telegraf Error: 400: Bad Request: can't ban members in private chats

Tags: telegraf.js

```
@On('message')
async ban(@Message('text') text: string, @Ctx() ctx: Context) {
    if (text === '✖️ Отмена') {
        await ctx.deleteMessage(this.#messageId)
        await ctx.deleteMessage()
        await ctx.reply('✔️', adminButtons())

        return ctx.scene.leave()
    }

    if (!Number(text)) return 'Только числа'

    const isUser = await this.userService.byTgUserId(+text)
    if (!isUser) return 'Пользователя нет в базе'

    await ctx.deleteMessage(this.#messageId)
    await ctx.deleteMessage()
    await ctx.reply('✔️', adminButtons())

    await ctx.banChatMember(+text)
    // await this.userService.removeUser(+text)

    return ctx.scene.leave()
}
```

I write a telegram bot with subscriptions with nestjs-telegraf, add the ability to ban the user of the telegram bot, get an error: Error: 400: Bad Request: can't ban members in private chats. I thought it would be logical to go to BotFather and make such a setting there if any, but I did not see it or missed it, looked through more details in the telegraf documentation methods for this task, tried it and did not get a positive result

Comment: How about blocking the user?